# How does android handle extra/alternate code while building APK?

Tags: android, performance, build, compilation, apk

Does writing different layouts for different screen sizes cost more size to final app apk. what happens to extra code and resources which is written to support different devices? do android devices receive only the code required for them-self or do they receive all the extra code.
basically I wanted to know How does android handle extra code while building APK? I am new to android development so please bare me if the question is too noob-ish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, everything you put in your APK will get distributed to everyone who downloads it.

The Play Store has a special way to provide multiple APKs to its client if you upload to it different APKs built for different configurations.  If you have uploaded multiple APKs with different types of device requirements, the Play Store will present the version of the APK that matches the device.  You can read more about that [at the official documentation here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).